# Single table per class hierarchy without discriminator column

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an existing table without discriminator column and I need to map it with single table hierarchy, how to map this?
here is my table

```
vehicle
========
vehicle_id
manufacturer
load_capacity
passenger_capacity
```

I have 3 classes

```
Vehicle.java
vehicleId;
manufacturer;

TransportationVehicle.java
loadCapacity;

PassengerVehicle.java
passengerCapacity;
```

Comment: Without discriminators hibernate would not be able to know what is a TransportationVehicle and a PassengerVehicle. Using @MappedSuperclass will not resolve the problem, Polymorphic queries are not possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you have no discriminator, then you need another condition to distinguish `TransportationVehicle` and `PassengerVehicle`. I guess in your case you could use:

- `TransportationVehicle`: `loadCapacity IS NOT NULL`
- `PassengerVehicle`: `passengerCapacity IS NOT NULL`

As JPA inheritance always needs a discriminator, you will have to use `@MappedSuperclass` and two `@Entity` classes with a corresponding `@Where` annotation:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Vehicle {
  @Id
  private Long vehicleId;
  private String manufacturer;
}

@Entity @Where(clause = "loadCapacity IS NOT NULL")
public class TransportationVehicle extends Vehicle {
  private int loadCapacity;
}

@Entity @Where(clause = "passengerCapacity IS NOT NULL")
public class PassengerVehicle extends Vehicle {
  private int passengerCapacity;
}
```

Major disadvantage of this approach compared with *real* JPA inheritance: You can't reference the mapped superclass in JPA - neither in queries (`SELECT v FROM Vehicle v`) nor in another entity (`@OneToOne Vehicle vehicle`).

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is use `@MappedSuperclass` on the `Vehicle` class and then map `TransportationVehicle` and `PassengerVehicle` to the same table.

This way you will inherit the mapped fields from `Vehicle` without having to map it as an entity.

Comment: And how does Hibernate know which rows to exclude from `TransportationVehicle` resp. `PassengerVehicle`?

Comment: Currently, it doesn't need to exclude anything. `vehicleId` and `manufacturer` are mapped in the base class. The extending classes inherit those and add one field, respectively. The column that is not used will not be taken into account - like having an extra unmapped column in the database.

Comment: But a query like `SELECT v FROM PassengerVehicle v` will include rows that are `TransportationVehicle` (have `passengerCapacity == NULL`  and `loadCapacity != NULL`). Imho this was not intended by the OP.

Comment: You can always include a suitable where clause to do the filtering - like you mentioned - passengerCapacity == NULL and loadCapacity != NULL or vice verse.

Comment: Having to think of that implicit constraint every time will make using the classes more complex than using just one `Vehicle` class with all fields together and `isTransportationVehicle()` or `isPassengerVehicle()`. That's why I added a solution that makes the constraint explicit.